# How will update list of lists at MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have MongoDB 2.2.2 and this collection:

> ```
> > db.my_collection.find({_id: ObjectId('51b0f9b74cfe6e668c4fd8f4')}).pretty()
> {
>   "_id" : ObjectId("51b0f9b74cfe6e668c4fd8f4"),
>   "campaigns" : [
>       {
>           "cs_strategy_name" : "HighestPosition",
>           "name" : "DefaultCampaign",
>           "campaign_id" : 0,
>           "_syskey" : "default",
>           "en_send_warn" : "Yes",
>           "minus_keywords" : [ ],
>           "login" : "test",
>           "fio" : "test test"
>       }
>   ],
>   "domain" : "defsite.ru",
>   "login" : "test",
>   "name" : "test",
>   "password" : "",
>   "site_id" : 2,
>   "status" : "new",
>   "surname" : "test"
> ```

Can you help me find a suitable update command for: `db.my_collection.campaigns.minus_keywords`?
It is an array inside another array.

Great thanks!

Comment: I have asked and I answer ;)
`db.my_collection.update({_id: ObjectId('51b0f9b74cfe6e668c4fd8f4'), 'campaigns._syskey' : 'default'}, {$set: { 'campaigns.0.minus_keywords': ['aaa', 'bbb']}})` Is there better case?

Comment: Just some suggestions, instead of specifying the element of the array to modify using the array index ('campaigns.0.minus_keywords'), consider using the positional operator $ ('campaigns.$.minus_keywords').   For more information on the positional operator, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/  Also, you can use the $push operator with $each instead of $set, if you want to append the list/array. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/

Answer (score 0):

In order to add items into an array within a mongoDB object , you can use $addToSet command , e.g.:

```
db.inventory.update(
   { _id: ObjectId('51b0f9b74cfe6e668c4fd8f4') },
   { $addToSet: { campaigns.minus_keywords: "accessories" } }
)
```

the above command ($addToSet) will only add the value iff it is not there.

What if I want to add (dublicate value)?
- you can use $push command instead.

For more information about $addToSet:
http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/operator/update/addToSet/
http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/operator/update/push/